# assuming $kT=1$ in $Z=\sum e^{-H}$ and $F=-\ln Z$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Some statistical physics book use:
$Z=\sum e^{-H}$  and $F=-\ln Z$ as definition for partition function and free energy.

I think they should be $Z=\sum e^{-\frac{H}{kT}}$ and $F=-kT \ln Z$

Are they assuming the temperature to be a constant kT=1 ?
Then how can we see any T depended phase transition?

Comment: kT is a variable, which is different from Plank constant or speed of light.

Comment: kT=0 can cause some trouble.  Also we can't take the derivative of kT anymore, or can we first assume kT is there, take its derivative first, and then set kT=1?

Comment: This is far from standard. Can you give specific references to the books that do this?

Comment: Quantum Phase Transitions 3rd ed. (Sachdev S.)   equation (3.1) (3.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $H' \equiv H/kT$ and $F' \equiv F / kT$.
Then you get

$$Z = \sum e^{-H / kT} = \sum e^{-H'}$$
and
$$F' = F / kT = -\ln Z \, .$$

The author is probably dropping the $'$ symbol to keep the notation compact.
This is annoying but common.

Comment: By the way, when trying to render equations dimensionless, defining new variables like $H' \equiv H / kT$ is *much* clearer than the usual ridiculous statement that e.g. we "set $kT$ to 1".